# How can I overload operator [] for a class containing an array of an abstract class in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

Here's my problem : I have 2 class which are specialization of an abstract base class.
I need to create a new class which is a container for those 2 class.

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void print() =0;
};

class A : public Base {
public:
  void print() { cout << "I am A"; };
};

class B : public Base {
public:
  void print() { cout << "I am B"; };
};

class ContainerBase {
public:
  ContainerBase() { arr = new Base*[10]; };
 ~ContainerBase() { delete[] arr; };
  Base & operator[](int index){ return *arr[index]; };
  Base & operator[](int index) const { return *arr[index]; };
private:
  Base **arr;
};

int main(){
  A a;
  B b;
  ContainerBase c;
  c[0] = &a;
  c[1] = &b;
  return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't compile. I guess that my problem is in the overload of the operator [] but I can't seem to find the good answer.

**Compilation error :** binary 'operator' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'A*' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
binary 'operator' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'B*' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please include the compilation error.

Comment: Related (but probably not the cause of the errors): `int index` should be `size_t index` and the `const` version should return a `const Base&`

Comment: You have quite a lot of syntax errors that have to do with semicolons. And `main()` must return `int`.

Comment: The compilation error is because it is not possible to have an expression of the form `some_reference = some_pointer` (unless `some_reference` is of a type that has an `operator=()` which accepts a pointer, which doesn't happen in your code).   Both the expressions `c[0] = &a` and `c[1] = &b` attempt to assign a reference to a pointer, since both versions of `ContainerBase::operator[]()` return a reference, and both `&a` and `&b` give results that are pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ContainerBase class, arr is defined as an array of pointers. This is correct. In this class, operator[] should return pointers:

```
Base*& operator[](int index) { return arr[index]; };
Base* operator[](int index) const { return arr[index]; };
```

That will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i had already tried to return pointers but I didn't know a reference on a pointer was a thing. This makes much more sense now !